# Refer to entire column in Access Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to calculate the percentile of an entire column of data in an Access Query using a custom function that refers to the Excel Object Model. Here is the code I have:

```
Public Function myPercentile25(x As Double) As Double
myPercentile25 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(x, 0.25)
End Function
```

I've added myPercentile25 function to the Query column in Design View where x equals AgedSalary using the following:

```
25P: myPercentile25([AgedSalary])
```

The issue I am having is the Query seems to be only taking the percentile for each individual row and not the entire column. I am more familiar with Excel where I would refer to column as AgedSalary:AgedSalary. Is there a similar syntax I can use in Access to take the percentile of the entire column?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to work with `TOP` in Access when you want a percentile:

```sql
select top 25 percent
    [agedSalary]
from [yourTable]
order by [agedSalary];
```

The above query will return the top 25% of the records. If you want the top value (i.e. the 25 percentile) you can nest the above query:

```sql
select max([agedSalary) as percentile
from (
    select top 25 percent [agedSalary] 
    from [yourTable] 
    order by [agedSalary])
) as a
```

---

If you want to do this using the design grid:

For the first query:

- In the "Columns" area (the lower half of the design view), below each column, there's an "Order by" combo where you can select "Ascending" or "Descending"
- You can set the TOP value in the property sheet of your query; in the Design ribbon click the "Property sheet" button

Once you are sure your query works (i.e. it selects the top 25% rows), you'll need to open the SQL view, cut the generated `SELECT` instruction and write this:

```sql
select a.*
from (
-- Paste HERE the SELECT you've just cut
) as a
```

Then return to the design grid, remove that `*` from the column grid and drag the desired field to the design view. Click on the Totals button in the Design ribbon (that big Sigma), and below the just dragged field, in the "Total" row select "Max"

Comment: Thanks. If the percentile falls somewhere between two values, this method of taking the Top doesn't split the value it just takes the top, correct?

Comment: @Chris2015 that's right. If you want to address this issue, you should write a VBA function to deal with it. However, you can't think in a Worksheet context: you must think on how to deal with this scenario using data rows. I suggest you take a look on `DAO` and `ADO` to understand how to work with RecordSets (I use `DAO`, but that's because I learned how to use it and became fond of it)

Comment: Is it possible to add the SELECT FROM ORDER BY directly in design view? Or must this be done in SQL view? I am running into syntax errors.

Comment: @Chris2015 Please check my updated answer. I've just added instructions on how to do this using the design view (you won't save yourself from using the SQL view, but just for a while)

Comment: Thanks! I used the instructions as you laid out and it worked as it should have. I am just a few days into learning Access so every task feels monumental, but you've been a great help.

Comment: @Chris2015 Happy to help. I once was where you stand right now. I recommend you get a good book; I learned Access reading "Running MS Access 97" by Jon Viescas... an old book, but I kept it until two years ago because it was a great reference (not much has changed in Access since then, besides eye-candy). If you find it in a library, it's a good learning resource... but of course there must be a more recent edition